# Webpack builds and my server serves a blank page, no errors. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webpack

Here is my current configuration and file structure. It successfully builds. There are no errors in my browser console. Just a blank page. I serve the `dist` folder. I installed all dependencies via `npm`. I had an initial error - `angular is not defined` - but I resolved that by installing the angular module. At the very least, it told me that server really is serving the `dist` folder.

[image: My file structure]

The html file in my dist folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Lightbox</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

My Webpack config

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './client/js/app.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass)$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: { mimetype: 'image/png' },
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()],
};
```

And my package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base dist"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-route": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-utils-pagination": "^0.11.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

My server

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path')
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.listen(port)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist')));
```

Comment: This being an Angular application, where is your mounting point, or, how are you bootstraping the application? Without taking care of this, the page is always going to be blank, as you are not attaching your module to a DOM element.

Comment: Very good point. I have that in the client folder, before it is compiled. I used the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to regenerate the html after each build. Do you know of a way off the top of your head to get `ng-view` & `ng-app` directives into the html?

Comment: I'd check the template documentation for the HtmlWebpackPlugin here: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md , the main document also explains how to add custom templates: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin

Comment: Thank you this handled the problem. Getting different errors, but different errors are good. If you want to make an answer I'll check it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are properly **bootstraping** your Angular application by adding your ng-app directive to the index HTML file template as explained in the official **HtmlWebpackPlugin** documentation:

- https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin
- https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md